# Eliminating off-of-ball roll in Trackball controls (with code/fix)

Tags: three.js

Is the intent of the TrackballControl to have a "border" outside the trackball that induces roll?  I personally dislike it.  It is a bit discontinuous, and does't really have a lot of purpose (imho).

If not, the function getMouseProjectionOnBall can be changed similar to the following.  This does two things (not necessarily "correctly"):

1. Normalize the radius to fill both axis
2. Map z values outside of the ball (ie where z was previously 0)

I find this a lot more natural, personally.

Thoughts?

```
 this.getMouseProjectionOnBall = function(clientX, clientY)  {
    var xnormalized = (clientX - _this.screen.width * 0.5 - _this.screen.offsetLeft) / (_this.screen.width / 2.0);
    var ynormalized = (_this.screen.height * 0.5 + _this.screen.offsetTop - clientY) / (_this.screen.height / 2.0);
    var mouseOnBall = new THREE.Vector3(
        xnormalized,
        ynormalized,
        0.0
    );

    var length = mouseOnBall.length();

    var ballRadius = 1.0;  // As a fraction of the screen 
    if (length > ballRadius * 0.70710678118654752440) {
        var temp = ballRadius / 1.41421356237309504880;
        mouseOnBall.z = temp * temp / length;

        // Remove old method.
        // This Left z = 0, which meant rotation axis
        // becomes z, which is a roll
        //mouseOnBall.normalize();

    } else {
        mouseOnBall.z = Math.sqrt(1.0 - length * length);
    }

    _eye.copy(_this.object.position).sub(_this.target);

    var projection = _this.object.up.clone().setLength(mouseOnBall.y);
    projection.add(_this.object.up.clone().cross(_eye).setLength(mouseOnBall.x));
    projection.add(_eye.setLength(mouseOnBall.z));

    return projection;

};
```

Comment: You should submit this as a pull request on github -- you'll get a lot more feedback that way. I've given up trying to understand how TrackballControls works for now and am impressed that you're brave enough to figure this out!